# How to automatically connect point

Tags: qgis

I have to draw all the rows connecting the 2 edges with a line. It's not so hard to it manually, but it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to connect the two edges of the rows automatically?

For example, if i call the edge on the right side X and the left edge AX (X will be the row number) can i give some kind of command to connect them automatically?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need to do? What do you mean by "draw all the rows" (maybe draw lines) "connecting the 2 edges" (edges are usually lines but from the discussions around the first answer I could assume you mean points). When should 2 points(?) be connected?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pluggin : Points2one
It will connect all points according to their order of creation.

Be careful, Points2One requires a field that indicates which points should be connected with each other. 
For example, all points that contain the fields 1 will be linked together, all the points with the two fields will be linked together etc..

[image]

Comment: It could be usefull, the fact it is that I take all the point with my instrumentation first on right edge and then on the left. It would take a long to walk allong the rows everytime.

Comment: I think it will be necessary to manually add with QGIS a new field in your layer that contain a similar identifier for each pair of points, and then use the pluggin.

Comment: I think i could easily add a new field, so with this plugin i will be able to connect point related to field such as "right" or "left"?

Comment: Yes, for example you set a point on the left with the ID 1, another point to the right with the same ID (ID 1). Another pair of points with the ID 2 etc..
Then the plugin will draw a line between all the points with the same identifier.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it now, I'll see if it works! Thank you again

Comment: I just tried the pluggin. It works perfectly to connect the dots with the same identifier.